# What should I look for when auditing a Firefox extension / plugin?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, audit, firefox, browser-extensions

I've been asked to do a security audit on a Firefox add-on developed by a third party. I am a web developer with a reasonable grasp of JavaScript but am not a browser security expert.

What kinds of things should I be looking for in the source code which might represent a security risk. Also, are there any effective tools for obfuscating browser extension source code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**IMPORTANT**: This is in noway a full list of the things you should look for, use this answer as an example, a first step in your path and research on your own. I've had a similar task long time ago. I had to security-wise review the code of a Firefox addon, I'm sure you'll easily find Chrome/other browsers' equivalents. Also have in mind the Extensions in Chrome run in a [Sandbox](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox).

---

**1. Anything that interacts with local files:**

Whenever the [`FileUtils.File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O) object is created and any of its methods is called

- Check if the local file access is a documented behavior. What are files being accessed? Why? Are they released successfully?
- Check if any local files are being modified. Is that a documented behavior? What are the modified files? Why?

**2. Anything that interacts with Windows Registry:**

Whenever an instance of [`nsIWindowsRegKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Accessing_the_Windows_Registry_Using_XPCOM) is created or any of its methods is called

- Is Windows Registry access a documented behavior? What keys are accessed? Why?
- Is Windows Registry modification a documented behavior? Is the modification temporarily? What keys are modified? Why?

**3. Anything that interacts with the cookies**

Whenever [`nsICookieService`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Cookies) is used

- Is accessing cookies a documented behavior? Why?
- To which domain do these cookies belong? Why?

**4.Any commands executed in the user's shell**

Whenever [`nsIProcess`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess) is created and any of its methods called (closely watch `.run()` and `.launch()`)

- Is executing commands a documented behavior? Why?
- What commands are being executed? Where is the output redirected?

**5. Any window/tab being accessed**

Whenever [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window) is accessed and/or any `getElement*` method is called (closely watch `createElement` calls that inject `<script>` elements.

- Is accessing a web page's DOM a documented behavior? Why?
- What are the elements added/removed/modified? Why?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I look forward to any additions if you manage to locate the pdf ;)

Comment: Should we be also looking at the `mozIStorageService`?

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you are auditing a new type of application you should look at the other types of vulnerabilities that have been found.  A good way of doing this is searching the CVE database. In the case of browser extensions you should look at this Defcon 17 talk: [Abusing Firefox Addons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vffa4FshXWY). Extensions are given elevated rights,  and can be extremely hazardous.

In terms of obfuscation,  any JS obfuscator should work.  An extension is just .js files in an archive.